# Export report from Eclipse plugin for Checkstyle

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, report, checkstyle

I am using Eclipse and I started to use FindBugs, PMD and Checkstyle with Eclipse plugin.
With FindBugs and PMD I can easily create reports witch can be exported as xml, html...

How can I do that with Eclipse CheckStyle plugin? Is there an option to export an report to an xml, txt or html?

Thank you very much for your answer in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click on the java project in the project explorer and select PMD | Generate reports.
It creates a report folder in your application and create violation report.

```
Select Window | Show View | Navigator
```

In Navigator view click on Project and then on the reports folder.

Comment: The question is about checkstyle, not PMD.